# react-instantsearch-dom:: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `hitComponent` of type `object` supplied to `Hits`, expected `function`

Tags: reactjs, react-instantsearch

I have created a class component for "Hit" and adding this to another file where I have used angolia react-instantsearch "Hits".
Check this code::

```
<Hits
    hitComponent={Hit}
    className="mb-30"
    showLoadingIndicator
/>
```

But gives me a warning::

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `hitComponent` of type
>   `object` supplied to `Hits`, expected `function`.

I cannot convert "Hit" to a functional component. Here how can I use class component value as a function?

Comment: Are you importing `Hit` properly? Can you and a codeSandbox link? does this `hitComponent={()=><div />}` shows the same warning?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but  could you try  something like :just wrap a function arroud it..a function  that returns component

```
hitComponent={(props) => <Hit {...props} />}
```

OR

```
   functions _Hit(props)
    {
    return <Hit {...props} />
    }
     hitComponent={_Hit}
```

Comment: Both versions work but in the first version you forgot `props` as argument to the function: `hitComponent={(props) => <Hit {...props} />}`

Comment: @GuiTeK Thanks for the update, fixed it in the answer.